# Get last page http request golang

Tags: http, go

I am doing an `http request`like this one:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
```

Then I am getting the `header link`:

```
link := resp.Header.Get("link")
```

Which gives me a result like this:

```
<page=3>; rel="next",<page=1>; rel="prev";<page=5>; rel="last"
```

**Question**

How can I parse this into a more legible way? I specifically trying to get the `last` page but `first`and `next`page should useful as well.

I tried with `Splits`and `Regular expressions`without success.

Comment: What part do you need from the link string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that is the format of the output? It looks like one of `;` should be a `,`.
A single Link http header with multiple values, should be of the format (notice the comma after "prev")

```
<page=3>; rel="next",<page=1>; rel="prev",<page=5>; rel="last"
```

The order should be split on `,` for each link. Split each link on `;` for values or key-value pairs, and then if they value matches `<(.*=.*)>`, discard the angle brackets and use the remaining key and value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution of how to match your page numbers.

http://play.golang.org/p/kzurb38Fwx

```
text := `<page=3>; rel="next",<page=1>; rel="prev";<page=2>; rel="last"`
re := regexp.MustCompile(`<page=([0-9]+)>; rel="next",<page=([0-9]+)>; rel="prev";<page=([0-9]+)>; rel="last"`)
matches:= re.FindStringSubmatch(text)
if matches != nil {
    next := matches[1]
    prev := matches[2]
    last := matches[3]
    fmt.Printf("next = %s, prev = %s, last = %s\n", next, prev, last)
}
```

Later Edit: you can probably also use the xml package to achieve the same result, by parsing that output as an XML, but you would need to transform your output a bit.